# Creating a cluster analysis on multiple variables

Tags: r, clustering

I am working on creating a cluster analysis for some very basic data in r for Windows [Version 6.1.76]. The groups themselves are countries and then I have 2 column with continuous numerical variables. I have applied a Ward Hierachical Method to the data

```
# Applying Ward Hierarchical Clustering
d = dist(conversion_set, method="euclidean")
fit = hclust(d, method="ward")
```

But I don't feel this represents what I am really trying to get to as it is just taking into account the first variable and disregarding the second. Is there a way to include both variables into the clustering calculations?

My data looks similar to this

Country - Var 1 - Var 2

US - 10 - 20

Canada - 5 - 30

....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this toy example

```
conversion_set <- data.frame(Country=c("United States", "Canada", "Mexico", 
                             "Guatemala", "Belize", "Honduras"), 
                             Var1=c(10,  5, 65, 10, 40, 70),
                             Var2=c(20, 30, 60, 80, 25, 90) ) 
numbers_only <- conversion_set[,-1]
rownames(numbers_only) <- conversion_set[,1]
# Applying Ward Hierarchical Clustering
d   <- dist(numbers_only, method="euclidean")
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward")
plot(fit)
```

which puts Belize closer to the United States and Canada than Guatemala is, and also puts Mexico and Honduras closer together than to Guatemala, as in

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think the core of my problem lies in the range of the data. Two of the countries have values in Var1 that are much larger than 3rd place and due to the vast difference I think they are being clustered together despite (what I think is the right answer) belonging in separate groups based on Var2

Comment: Then you do not want to use a Euclidean metric on unscaled variables